# "Entity Framework Provider type could not be loaded?" in QA; works in Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

We have a VBA script hitting a web service in our MVC application; we're receiving this error on our QA server, but not on our test server:
[image: Entity Framework type cannot be loaded error]

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097516/net-mvc-error-the-entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971910/the-entity-framework-provider-type-oracle-manageddataaccess-entityframework-co) here at StackOverflow which have been great in helping me understand the cause of the error, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this error would occur in QA but not Test? The builds are literally copied and pasted to deploy to QA. The web.configs are identical. The servers are, as far as I can tell, the same.

Thank you for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the EntityFramework DLL was added to the ASP.NET MVC Project. All projects that call database methods must have the EntityFramework's DLL.

Comment: Why would it be added in Test but not QA, when it's exactly the same project? Is the DLL stored somewhere weird that it wouldn't be picked up in a copy?

Comment: It depends on how did you copy them. Are you saying that in development, it works, but in production doesn't?

Comment: I feel dumb! I went back just to make sure the DLLs were there and they weren't. I guess because the file structures are slightly different between the servers, the DLLs weren't being inherited like I thought they should be. Thank you SO MUCH!